# Can't get nullable property with Entity Framework code-first

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, nullable, fluent

I have POCO class `Message` as follow.

```
public class Message
{
    //<Summary>
    //Fields...
    //</Summary>

    //other fields

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I try to get a nullable `UserId` field, for this I write

```
 public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
```

But it doesn't work, then I try FluentApi as follow:

```
 Property(mes => mes.UserId).IsOptional();
```

But it doesn't work again. I don't know any other approach. Please, help me.

**SOLUTION:** I used Fulent api HasRequired-HasMany relationship before Property-HasOptional. So it give not null property.

Comment: what is type generated for UserId in database..

Comment: is it identity column ? primary

Comment: Yes, @vishal sharman. It appropriate System.Guid class in .Net. So I solve my problem